# JsonSyntaxException при восстановлении объекта. конфликт типов данных JAVA

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Меня не устроило официальное приложение одного хостинга. Решил сделать своё...

Сделал. Всё хорошо работает при включённом сервере, но когда сервер выключен выдаёт **JsonSyntaxException**. Вопрос в том, к**ак сделать корректную работу в обоих случаях**.

Ответ API при включённом сервере:

```
{
"status":"OK",
"online":1,
"data":{
"b":{
"type":"gamespy3",
"ip":"46.174.50.28",
"c_port":"25784",
"q_port":"25784",
"s_port":"25784",
"status":1
},
"s":{
"game":"gamespy3",
"name":"ScCraft",
"map":"-",
"players":1,
"playersmax":10,
"password":0
},
"e":{
"gametype":"SMP",
"game_id":"MINECRAFT",
"version":"1.11.2",
"plugins":"",
"map":"world",
"hostport":"25784",
"hostip":"46.174.50.28"
},
"p":[{"name":"sashaqwert"},{"name":""}],"t":[]
},
"server_id":"937",
"server_name":"Minecraft",
"server_address":"46.174.50.28:25784",
"server_maxslots":"10",
"server_location":"\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f, \u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430",
"server_type":"\u041f\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0438\u0447\u043d\u044b\u0439",
"server_dateblock":"1498293440",
"server_daystoblock":23
}
```

При выключенном сервере:

```
{
"status":"OK",
"online":0,
"data":{
"b":{
"type":"gamespy3",
"ip":"46.174.50.28",
"c_port":"25784",
"q_port":"25784",
"s_port":"25784",
"status":0
},
"s":{
"game":"",
"name":"",
"map":"",
"players":0,
"playersmax":0,
"password":""
},
"e":[],"p":[],
"t":[]
},
"server_id":"937",
"server_name":"Minecraft",
"server_address":"46.174.50.28:25784",
"server_maxslots":"10","server_location":"\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f, \u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430",
"server_type":"\u041f\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0438\u0447\u043d\u044b\u0439",
"server_dateblock":"1529397440",
"server_daystoblock":166
}
```

Из приведённых ответов видно, что тип поля "oassword" - цисло (при вкл. сервере) и строка (при выкл. сервере). Есть ещё несколько критических отличий.

JAVA-класс (самодельный) [здесь](https://github.com/sashaqwert/ArenaControl/blob/edc02b6ab564b6b6e10a133da4928c1fa4298390/app/src/main/java/ru/sccraft/arenacontrol/Server.java#L165).

Ошибка выгледит так:

```
01-04 18:06:55.429 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
01-04 18:06:55.429 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:227)
01-04 18:06:55.429 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:217)
01-04 18:06:55.429 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
01-04 18:06:55.429 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
01-04 18:06:55.429 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
01-04 18:06:55.429 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
01-04 18:06:55.429 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at ru.sccraft.arenacontrol.Server.update(Server.java:245)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at ru.sccraft.arenacontrol.ServerActivity$1Поток.doInBackground(ServerActivity.java:516)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at ru.sccraft.arenacontrol.ServerActivity$1Поток.doInBackground(ServerActivity.java:512)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
01-04 18:06:55.430 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
01-04 18:06:55.431 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
01-04 18:06:55.431 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
01-04 18:06:55.431 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
01-04 18:06:55.431 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539)
01-04 18:06:55.431 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextInt(JsonReader.java:1201)
01-04 18:06:55.431 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:225)
01-04 18:06:55.431 4331-4684/ru.sccraft.arenacontrol W/System.err:  ... 20 more
```

Comment: в одном случае у вас password - строка, в другом - число

Comment: @etki Из-за этого и проблема. На ответы сервера повлиять не могу.

Comment: Отсюда единственным решением выглядит только установить тип поля Object и разбираться на принимающей стороне. Либо копаться в настройках GSON - может, он позволит десериализовать такое как null. Ну или написать кастомный класс и кастомный обработчик класса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлягаю **не совскм правильное**, но работающее решение.

1) Должны быть **одинаковые типы** данных. (Это не возможно!), следовательно, не используем эту переменную и **приводим к Object** (для сохранения синтаксиса).

То есть, заменяем код:

```
class S {
                String game;
                String name;
                String map;
                int players; //количество игроков
                int playersmax;
                int password; //String password;
}
```

на этот:

```
class S {
    String game;
    String name;
    String map;
    int players; //количество игроков
    int playersmax;
    Object password; //int password; String password;
}
```

2) Ещё есть проблема некорректного (с точки зрения GSON) **объявления null**, то есть:

```
"e":[] //Это воспринимается, как массив = null, хотя это объект
```

GSON ожидает:

```
"e":{} // null объект
```

Это решается через **замену символов** в строке (String.replace):

```
JSON = JSON.replace("\"e\":[]", "\"e\":{}");
```

Но, это бы не помогло, если бы это место встречалось более одного раза.